# Calculating sum of sims values in pbias when obs includes NA

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

```
sims = c(2,5,3,5,5,3)
obs  = c(1,4,NA,NA,7,4)
```

Using the `hydroGOF` R package I can calculate the percentage bias as

```
pbias(sims,obs,na.rm=T)
```

However, is there a way to output the sum of `sims` used in the `pbias` calculation (i.e. 2+5+5+3 because the hydroGOF manual states that "When an ’NA’ value is found at the i-th position in obs OR sim, the i-th value of obs AND sim are removed before the computation") rather than the actual sum of sims (i.e. what would be returned by sum(sims) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with any two vectors like this:

```
sum(sims[!is.na(obs)])
```